# strange border on custom scrollbar in textarea resizer

Tags: css, sass, webkit, scrollbar

I am adding custom webkit scrollbar to textarea, however I noticed there is a strange border for the resizer, can this be removed?

[image]

```
@mixin scrollbar($size, $foregroundColor, $backgroundColor ){

  // IE ======
  scrollbar-highlight-color: $foregroundColor;
  scrollbar-track-color:$backgroundColor;
  // Webkit =====
  &::-webkit-scrollbar {
    @include size($size $size);
  }
  &::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: $foregroundColor;
  }
  &::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background: $backgroundColor;
  }

  &::-webkit-scrollbar-corner {
    border:none;
  }
  &::-webkit-resizer {

  }
  &::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    border:none;
  }
}

@include scrollbar(8px, rgba(0,0,0,0.3), #fff );
```

Comment: Maybe check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7670194/html5-css3-change-the-look-of-resize-handles

Comment: ok, i will add a custom style there, for anyone who have same problem can take a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/q5kdr/33/